# Feature selection in R

Tags: feature-selection

I have  a database which deals with categorical data with 50+ features and 30,000+ rows.
The objective of the data is to find combination of features which occurs maximum number of times.
For this I have been using Association rule mining(Market basket analysis).

I need help in reducing the number of features within the database(feature selection)

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like a PCA if your feature space has a numeric component. If on the other hand it has a all binary and n-ary data, I would use something like multi-dimensional scaling or stochastic neighborhood embedding.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling

This approach would require you to try many embeddings and find the one that reduces the stress optimally.

Another approach is to transform the entire dataset to a manifold and then you can use something like IsoMap.

Without further indication of the type of data it is difficult to suggest anything else.